# Comparing an empty string against a vowel in a condition statement returning True

Tags: python

The code simply subtracts 1 from `syllables` if consecutive vowels are encountered. However, when we iterate in the inner for loop for the second word `arms`, the variable `prev` is an empty string again, which should make `if (char in vowels) and (prev in vowels):` False, but it executes the line `syllables -= 1` anyway and I don't understand why.

```
string = "take arms against a sea of troubles, And by opposing end them? To die: to sleep."

vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
syllables = 0

for word in string.split():
    prev = ""
    for char in word:
        if (char in vowels) and (prev in vowels):
            syllables -= 1
        prev = char
        
print(syllables)
```

Comment: Any empty string will be inside a string, i.e. `"" in string` will always evaluate to `True`.

Comment: "However, when we iterate in the inner for loop for the second word arms, the variable prev is an empty string again, which should make if (char in vowels) and (prev in vowels): False" I don't understand your reasoning. I think it is clear that, given that `prev` is an empty string, that `prev` will be found `in vowels`. Why do you think it should not be found?